# Top 5 - same formula but different output

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

In this [example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16R1eU-aiiyBdnvYBD08nXN6dCtBUpJKgQqk5BhK_GzU/edit?usp=sharing) I have Data-sheet and Statistics-sheet. I am trying to pull Top 5.

I have tried this:

```
=IFERROR(IF(LEN(A2:A)<>"";ARRAYFORMULA(MAX(COUNTIF(A2:A;A2:A)));"");"")
```

And this:

```
=IFERROR(IF(LEN(A2:A);ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX(A2:A;MATCH(MAX(COUNTIF(A2:A;A2:A));COUNTIF(A2:A;A2:A);0)));"1");"2")
```

It works UNTIL I edit the data.
Then I tried this:

```
=IFERROR(IF(LEN(Data!A2:A)<>"";ARRAYFORMULA(MAX(COUNTIF(Data!A2:A;Data!A2:A)));"");"")
```

And this:

```
=IFERROR(IF(LEN(Data!A2:A);ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX(A2:A;MATCH(MAX(COUNTIF(A2:A;A2:A));COUNTIF(A2:A;A2:A);0)));"1");"2")
```

And now I get a completely different result.

What is the better way to do this?

Comment: So you want to pull the top 5 rows in the spreadsheet?

Comment: Yes. I want to pull Top 5 from A-E even though the data will change occassionally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY(Data!B:B; 
 "select count(B),B
  where B is not null
  group by B
  order by count(B) desc
  limit 5
  label count(B)''")
```

for B:E range:

```
=QUERY({Data!B:B; Data!C:C; Data!D:D; Data!E:E}; 
 "select count(Col1),Col1
  where Col1 is not null
  group by Col1
  order by count(Col1) desc
  limit 5
  label count(Col1)''")
```

Comment: Works perfectly! This is why some people should stick to building houses. I still live to try but I would never have guessed how to fix this. Thank  You.